# How to vertically align inline element and inline-block element

Tags: html, css

Say I have the following code

```css
p {
  display: inline;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
 <p>
     Some  text
     <div>
     </div>
    </p>
```

What is created is this

[image]

Here the inline and inline-block elements are not vertically centered.
How would I make it look like this :

[image]

Comment: the duplicate is about images but it's exactly the same as your div here behave as the image in the duplicate

Comment: `div` cannot be wrapped into `p` tag

Comment: A `p` tag cannot contain a `div` element. `p` tags can only contain [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content).

Comment: added another duplicate related to what @AbhishekPandey said

Answer (score 0):

I have used `flex` css and also add one new `div`
I hope this will help you.

```css
p {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
}
.inner-div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
}
.outer-div{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-div">
  <p>Some text</p>
    <div class="inner-div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: doing this will make he use of inline and inline-block useless

Answer (score -1):

just add float left to

tag

```
p{
display: inline;
float:left;
}
```

This will align both element properly